# Find the values of a and b that makes the following function differentiable

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

I am told for the following piecewise function:

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      ax+b, & x>-1; \\
      bx^2-3ax+4, & x\leq -1 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

I am asked to find the values of $a$ and $b$ that make $f(x)$ differentiable.

So I simply differentiated $f(x)$ to get:

$$f'(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      a, & x>-1; \\
      2bx-3a, & x\leq -1 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

So since a differentiable function must be continuous, I get that:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to -1^-}}(a)=f'(-1)$

So this implies:

$a=-2b-3a$

$4a=-2b$

$-2a=b$

So that means as long as for any $a$, if I get a $b$ value such that $-2a=b$, $f(x)$ is differentiable. Is that correct?

Comment: You want $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}[f(-1-\delta)-f(-1+\delta)]=0$ and $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}[f'(-1-\delta)-f'(-1+\delta)]=0$

Comment: Shouldn't that be the limit as x approaches -1?

Comment: Something isn't right here, first you should prove the continuity in -1 then the differentiability @Future Math person

Comment: @valer Continuity in $f(x)$ does not imply continuity in $f'(x)$. Consider $f(x)=|x|$

Comment: Because if you solve the right and left limit as x aproaches -1 you get a, and with the differentiability in -1 you should get b. I know because i solved a bunch of these.

Comment: You know that to have f'(x) , f should be continous don't you? And why do you need continuity in f'(x) again?

Comment: @valer I get what you're saying but then what about a question like this? https://imgur.com/Xa1XV6t . Would the a and b values not be different??

Comment: Also watch out that there can be differentiable functions without the derivative being continuous.  So, you really need to fall back on the definition of derivative $f'(-1) = \lim_{x \to -1} \frac{f(x) - f(-1)}{x - (-1)}$.  (Though if you know the two functions agree at $x=-1$, then you could take the shortcut $\lim_{x \to -1^-} \frac{f(x) - f(-1)}{x - (-1)} = \frac{d}{dx} (ax + b) |_{x = -1}$ and similarly for the right-hand limit.)

Comment: I got it now! Thank you for showing me the proper way :) .

Answer (score 2):

There are **two** conditions that need to be met

- **Continuity** $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow -1} (ax+b) = \lim_{x \rightarrow -1} (bx^2 - 3ax+4)$$
- **Smoothness** $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow -1} \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} (ax+b) = \lim_{x \rightarrow -1} \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}(bx^2 - 3ax+4)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the left and right derivatives as $x$ approaches $-1$. You should also ensure that the function is continuous at $-1$. Doing both the above will give you two equations in $a$ and $b$ which you can then solve to find out their values.

Comment: @FutureMathperson, please do not change your posts in order to make them suit the given answers. For instance, in the initial version of your question you computed some limits in $0$, not in $-1$. Once this has been noticed in the above answer, you altered the question, making part of the answer incomprehensible to somebody not looking at the edit history of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is true, but also note that for the function’s derivative to be continuous the function must be continuous itself. Therefore you get another condition for $a$ and $b$.  Using the second equation  i.e.  $ax+b=bx^2-3ax+4$
At $x=-1$ we get(you can verify this yourself) $a=-1$. Therefore condition for $b$ is also attained using the first(the one you framed/ eq for continuous derivative ) equation.

Comment: Your post adds nothing new to what has already been said, and is also very poorly formatted, therefore difficult to read.

Comment: I am really sorry I had not seen the post that had been put up.